# Category product showing wrong image

Tags: product, magento2.3, product-images

I have a strange problem with my Magento 2.3.4 installation.

A product on a category page is showing an image not uploaded for the product.

The image shown below belongs to a different product!!!

[image]

Image shown does not appear in admin.

[image]

***Have tried flushing cache, reindexing and running catalog:images:resize but with no change, still showing wrong image.***

Also the same image is appearing in the new products widget on front-page.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: you have checked with magento luma theme and same issue facing? i think problem in your custom theme

Comment: Thanks for your comment, tried Luma theme, same result.